# Cox, Little, O'Shea exercise 2.3.11

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

Let $f_1,\dots, f_s\in k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ and $LM(f_i)=x^{\alpha(i)}$ the leading monomial of $f_i$. Define

\begin{align*}
&Δ_1 = α(1) + \mathbb{Z}^n_{≥0},\\
&Δ_2 = (α(2) + \mathbb{Z}^n_{≥0}) \setminus Δ_1,\\
&\;\vdots\\
&Δ_s = (α(s) + \mathbb{Z}^n_{≥0}) \setminus
\left(\bigcup^{s−1}_{i=1}
Δ_i
\right)
,\\
&\overline{Δ} = \mathbb{Z}^n_{≥0} \setminus
\left(\bigcup^{s}_{i=1}
Δ_i
\right)
.
\end{align*}

I've been asked several questions about the division algorithm for multivariate polynomials described in [Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Ideals%2C%20Varieties%2C%20and%20Algorithms%20%284th%20ed.%29%20%5BCox%2C%20Little%20%26%20O%27Shea%202015-06-14%5D.pdf) using this construction. One of them, which I've solved:

> (c) Show that in the expression $f = q_1 f_1 + \dots + q_s f_s + r$
>    computed by the division algorithm, for every $i$, every monomial
>    $x^β$ in $q_i$ satisfies $β + α(i) ∈ Δ_i$, and every monomial $x^γ$ in
>    $r$ satisfies $γ ∈ \overline{Δ}$.

But then, there's the following:

> Show that there is exactly one expression $f = q_1 f_1 + \dots + q_s
>  f_s + r$ satisfying the properties given in part (c).

How can I show that uniqueness?

So far I've thought that, since $LT(q_1f_1)=LT(f)=LT(q_1'f_1)$, it must be the case that $LT(q_1)=LT(q_1')$, but I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: Can you show the uniqueness when $s = 1$?  How about $s=n=1$?

Comment: @EricTowers I actually can't. The case $n=1$ is probably not relevant because the division algorithm in $k[x]$ has much better properties than the multivariate case.

Comment: Note that you can induct on the sequence of variables.  $k[x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}][x_n]$ is a univariate polynomial ring (with coefficients in a multivariate polynomial ring).

Comment: @EricTowers I see. Does it mean that it suffices to prove uniqueness for $n=1$ and a general $s$?

Comment: I'm not willing to agree to that sufficiency.  I am willing to say that you should have an easy double induction, if you can't think of an easier way to go.

Comment: @EricTowers I guess for $s=1$ I could use an argument similar to the univariate case replacing the degree by the multidegree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two expressions
\begin{align*}
f &= q_1f_1+\dots+q_sf_s+r \tag{1}\\
f &= q_1'f_1+\dots+q_s'f_s+r' \tag{2}
\end{align*}
satisfying (c). Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$, we get
\begin{equation}
0 = (q_1-q_1')f_1+\dots+(q_s-q_s')f_s+r-r'. \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Suppose that $q_i \neq q_i'$ for some $1 \leq i \leq s$. The idea now is to expand the products $(q_j-q_j')f_j$ in $(3)$ and to look at the largest monomials appearing before proceeding with the cancellation. More precisely, if we let $x^{\beta(j)}$ denote the leading monomial of $q_j-q_j'$, we want to consider the largest monomial in
\begin{equation*}
S = \left\{x^{\beta(j)+\alpha(j)}:1 \leq j \leq s\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Let $1 \leq k \leq s$ be the smallest index for which $x^{\beta(k)+\alpha(k)}$ is the largest monomial in $S$. We claim that there must be an index $k < \ell \leq s$ for which $x^{\beta(\ell)+\alpha(\ell)}$ is also the largest monomial in $S$. Indeed, the overall expression in $(3)$ is $0$, so $x^{\beta(k)+\alpha(k)}$ must appear again in one of the subsequent expansions, say $(q_\ell-q_\ell')f_\ell$, for there to be cancellation (note that it cannot appear in $r-r'$ as all the monomials in $r-r'$ are in $\overline{\Delta}$, so in particular they are not divisible by $x^{\alpha(k)}$). Moreover, it cannot appear as $x^{\beta_\ell+\alpha_\ell}$ for either $\beta_\ell < \beta(\ell)$ or $\alpha_\ell < \alpha(\ell)$, as this would contradict the maximality of $x^{\beta(k)+\alpha(k)}$. We have thus reached a contradiction: $x^{\beta(\ell)}$ is a monomial in either $q_\ell$ or $q_\ell'$ such that $x^{\beta(\ell)+\alpha(\ell)}$ is divisible by $x^{\alpha(k)}$, i.e. $\beta(\ell)+\alpha(\ell) \notin \Delta_\ell$. Therefore, we conclude that $q_i = q_i'$ for all $1 \leq i \leq s$, from which it follows directly that $r = r'$ as well.